# Creating a Win32_LocalTime _instancemodificationevent non repeating event

Tags: events, wmi, wmi-query, timed

I have a question that I dont seem to be able to find an answer to. I am using WMI to create some timed events, and so far they are working well. The events repeat on the scheduled cycle as expected. I am now searching for a way to create a 'one-time' event that does not repeat and cant seem to figure it out or find an answer anywhere.

The following is an example from the MSDN website that creates a repeating event:

```
// Win32_LocalTime and Win32_UTCTime reside in root\cimv2 namespace. 
// Defining the EventNamespace allows the filter
// to be compiled in any namespace.
instance of __EventFilter as $FILT1
{
    Name  = "wake-up call";
    Query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WHERE "    
    "TargetInstance ISA \"Win32_LocalTime\" AND "
    "TargetInstance.Hour = 0 AND TargetInstance.Minute = 0 AND "
 "TargetInstance.Second = 0";
    QueryLanguage = "WQL";
    EventNamespace = "root\\cimv2";
};
```

What I would like is to make it non-repeating. Any ideas?

Cheers

The Frog

Comment: Just as a passing thought, would adding the date in some fashion help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [__InstanceModificationEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class is a intrinsic event which reports when a change was made to a instance of a WMI class, in this case is listening the [`Win32_LocalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class which return the current time. Now if you want create a non repeating event you can add the the year , month and day properties to the WQL sentece.

```
instance of __EventFilter as $FILT1
{
    Name  = "wake-up call";
    Query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WHERE "    
    "TargetInstance ISA \"Win32_LocalTime\" AND "
    "TargetInstance.Hour = 0 AND TargetInstance.Minute = 0 AND TargetInstance.Second = 0 AND "
    "TargetInstance.Year=2012 AND TargetInstance.Month=7 AND TargetInstance.Day=12";
    QueryLanguage = "WQL";
    EventNamespace = "root\\cimv2";
};
```

Comment: Thankyou for clarifying that for me. Do you know if this is the same for registering a permanent event? Can a permanent event be consumed even after a machine restart? If the event passes while the machine is powered off will there still be a notification?

Comment: Q : Do you know if this is the same for registering a permanent event? A : Yes

Comment: Q : same for registering a permanent event? Can a permanent event be consumed even after a machine restart? A : Yes, that is one of the  differences between a temporary and permenent event.

Comment: Q : If the event passes while the machine is powered off will there still be a notification? A: I don't think so because in this case the event is monitoring a particular set of conditions and the WMI is not aware which that conditions are related to datetime factors. So if the conditions doesn't match the event will not be fired.

Comment: Thankyou for answering these questions. I appreciate the guidence. I can now move forwardf with my project. Thankyou very much.